# CSS Positioning with Cargo Collective

Tags: html, css, positioning

The site i'm working on is http://cargocollective.com/amytdatta

I am trying to position the Running on Cargo link at the right side of the top nav bar.
In the theme i'm using there used to be a search box positioned exactly there, so I hid the search and tried copying the search CSS to the Cargo link CSS. Here it is:

```
.cargo_link {
float: right;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
color: #cccccc;
padding: 0 0 0 25px;
width: 160px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: right;
border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

Some fiddling with z-index values has made the Cargo link visible again.

I'm still unable to place it where I want, though. Here is the CSS for the Search Box (which i've made visible for now):

```
#search_form {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
padding: 0;
}


#search_form #search_term {
background: #f5f5f5;
border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
border-top: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
border-right: 0;
color: #999999;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 12px;
padding: 0 0 0 25px;
width: 160px;
}
```

I basically wish the Cargo Link to precisely replace the Search box.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: Please don't make people reverse-engineer your page. Please post the relevant HTML.

Comment: Sorry! Unfortunately, i'm using Cargo Collective which just gives me access to the stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#nav_wrapper` element has a `background: whiteSmoke;` property which hides whatever's under it.

You either put the cargo link in the wrong element (i.e. not inside `#nav_wrapper` but under it). or you should not have a background on `#nav_wrapper`

Edit:

I'm guessing you should move your `<div class="cargo_link">` to right after `<div class="page_nav">`'s closing tag

Comment: I definitely need the `#nav_wrapper` to have the background color so that the content scrolls under it.

Comment: then set #nav_wrapper's z-index to something lower (let's say 50) and make .cargo_link have position:relative and z-index: 51

Answer (score 0):

You have `<div id="nav_wrapper">` with `position:fixed` and `z-index:999`, that's making the cargo_link appear behind the nav_wrapper...

Comment: I tried giving the Cargo link a higher z-index, but that still didn't work. And I want the nav_wrapper to always be in the middle of the browser.